# Filter data and then copy and paste the distinct values

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I have some experience in VBA but I am not an expert and need some advice on how to solve my problem. I have a database that I need to apply 2 filters on. I have the following code for the two filters:

```
Sub Filtering()
    'Filter Plant
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D1")) = False Then
     If Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D1") = "All" Then
      Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:X").AutoFilter 'removes any filters
     Else
      Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:X").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D1")
     End If
    End If
    
    'Filter SLoc
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D2")) = False Then
     If Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D2") = "All" Then
      Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:X").AutoFilter 'removes any filters
     Else
      Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:X").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D2")
     End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Once that is completed, I need to extract the Distinct Values and paste then into a different sheet. I know that the second half can be achieved by manipulating the following code:

```
Sub ExtractDistinct()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("Inventory").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("Inventory").Range("H2:H" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("D4"), _
    Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Using the code above gives me the distinct value that I am looking for, but it does not do it to the filtered range that I had from the ".AutoFilter" code from before. It gives me the distinct values from the data unfiltered, and removes any filters that I had on the data.

I was able to get the ".autofilter" to filter the raw data in the worksheet I was using but having the data physically filtered in excel is not what I am looking for (Also seems to be taxing on the processing). I want to be able to filter the data from column A and B, then extract all of the distinct values from the **Filtered Data From** Column C and copy that to a separate sheet(not a new sheet).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could we see the `AutoFilter` code where you filter the database?

Comment: I updated my post to have the codes that I am currently using as of right now. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unique Values from Filtered Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub filterUnique()
    
    ' Declare a boolean which will indicate if successful.
    Dim dataCopied As Boolean
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Define Criteria Values.
    Dim Crit1 As Variant
    Crit1 = wb.Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D1").Value
    Dim Crit2 As Variant
    Crit2 = wb.Worksheets("Material Planning").Range("D2").Value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Inventory")
    ' Remove AutoFilter.
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Define Souce Range (you may need to do it another way).
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Apply filters to Source Range.
    If Not IsEmpty(Crit1) Then
        If Crit1 = "All" Then
            srg.AutoFilter
        Else
            srg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Crit1
        End If
    End If
    If Not IsEmpty(Crit2) Then
        If Crit2 = "All" Then
            srg.AutoFilter
        Else
            srg.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Crit2
        End If
    End If
 
    ' Attempt to define Copy Range.
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = srg.Columns(3).Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) _
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If Copy Range was defined (i.e. a reference to it was created)...
    If Not crg Is Nothing Then
        ' Write unique (distinct) values to Unique Dictionary.
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim arg As Range
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim Key As Variant
        For Each arg In crg.Areas
            For Each cel In arg.Cells
                Key = cel.Value
                If Not IsError(Key) Then
                    If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                        dict(Key) = Empty
                    End If
                End If
            Next cel
        Next arg
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = dict.Count
        If rCount > 0 Then
            ' Write unique values from Unique Dictionary to Data Array.
            Dim Data As Variant
            Dim i As Long
            ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
            For Each Key In dict.Keys
                i = i + 1
                Data(i, 1) = Key
            Next Key
            ' Write values from Data Array to Dictionary Worksheet.
            With wb.Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("D4")
                .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
                .Resize(i).Value = Data
                dataCopied = True
            End With
        End If
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If dataCopied Then
        MsgBox "Unique values transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing transferred.", vbExclamation, "Fail?"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that worked flawlessly! The processing time for it was also super quick, amazing!

Answer (score 1):

This proposed solution:

•   Uses [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement) instead of nested `IF`s
•   Uses [For Each...Next statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) to avoid a double loop over `Areas` and `Cells` (i.e. `For Each Cell in Range.Cells`)
•   Does not validate the filtered values as they are the result of the criteria applied (i.e. the objective is to extract the unique values of whatever resulted from the filtering of the data).
•   Uses a line like this: `Dictionary.Item(Key) = Any value` where `Key` = `Cell.Value`, to ensure that only one record per `Cell.Value` is added to the dictionary.

```
Sub Data_Filter_N_Extract()
    Data_AutoFilter
    Data_Extract_Unique
    End Sub

Sub Data_AutoFilter()
Dim vCrt_A As Variant, vCrt_B As Variant

    Rem Get Criteria
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Material Planning")
        vCrt_A = .Range("D1").Value
        vCrt_B = .Range("D2").Value
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A:X")
        
        Rem Filter Plant
        Select Case vCrt_A
        Case vbNullString                                               'NO ACTION!. Any filter already applied to column [A] will stay.
        Case "All":         .AutoFilter                                 'Removes all filters from the entire range [A:X]
        Case Else:          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vCrt_A     'Apply filter as per [D1] value
        End Select
                
        Rem Filter SLoc
        Select Case vCrt_B
        Case vbNullString:                                              Rem NO ACTION!. Any filter already applied to the column [B] will stay.
        Case "All":         .AutoFilter                                 'Removes all filters from the entire range [A:X]
        Case Else:          .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=vCrt_B     'Apply filter as per [D2] value
        End Select
    
    End With

    End Sub


Sub Data_Extract_Unique()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Dtn As Object, Cll As Range
Dim lRow As Long, sMsg As String
    
    Rem Set output cell & clear prior data
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dictionary").Range("D4")
    With Rng
        .Resize(-3 + .Worksheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents
        .Value = "In progress…"     'Indicate that a process has started
    End With
    
    Rem Extract & post unique values
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory").Columns("C:C")
        
        Rem Get last row of columns [C] in Data
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Rem Validate Last Row
        Select Case lRow
        
        Case 1      'Last row = 1 - Filter returned 0 records
            sMsg = "Filtered data shows 0 records to extract!"
        
        Case 2      'Last row = 2 - Filter returned 1 record
            sMsg = "1 Unique value extracted from filtered data"
            Rng.Value = .Cells(2).Value:

        Case Else   'Last row = any other row - Filter returned several recorda
        
            Rem Use a dictionary to filter out duplicated values
            Set Dtn = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            With Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(lRow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                For Each Cll In .Cells
                    Dtn.Item(Cll.Value) = Cll.Value
            
            Next: End With
            
            Rem Post Dictionary to the Output Range (Keys or Items - pick one)
            With Dtn
                sMsg = .Count & " Unique values extracted from filtered data"
                Rem Any of these two lines would work as the Keys and Items are the same (pick one)
                Rng.Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
                'Rng.Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Items)
            End With
    
    End Select: End With

    MsgBox sMsg, vbInformation, "Data Extract Unique"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me that `Areas` in my solution is 'redundant' (incorrect), i.e. `Cells` will 'cover' all cells even if the range is non-contiguous. That's a valuable lesson for me. Note that `Rows` and `Columns` will only refer to the first `Area` of a non-contiguous range, which led me to use `Areas` in the first place.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I would not call it incorrect, as it returns all the correct results. Note that in some cases it's more efficient to use areas, (i.e return of all items in a non-contiguous range).